# Optimisation of RAM usage for cluster jobs impacts data transfer in HPC environment. Any way to turn off caching to RAM in cp or rsync commands?

Tags: linux, caching, rsync, hpc, cp

My problem is related to performing computer simulations on the large scale HPC cluster. I have a program that does MC simulation. After some part of the simulation is passed, the results are saved into files, and the simulation continues writing to the same part of memory as from the start. Thus, the program doesn't need all that much RAM to run (and we are talking about really low memory usage, like ~25MB). However, the total data generated over time are 10 or 100 times greater than that. The jobs are handled in the normal fashion: job data is copied to scratch partition, program runs on the node, results are returned from scratch to jobdir.

Now, everything would be dandy if it wasn't for the fact that when submitting a job to SLURM, I have to declare the amount o RAM assigned for the job. If I declare something around the real program usage, say 50MB, I have a problem with getting back the results. After a week-long simulation, data are copied from scratch to job directory, and the copy operation is cached to RAM, violating the job RAM setting. Ultimately, the job is killed by SLURM. I have to manually look for this data on scratch and copy them back. Obviously, this is not feasible for few thousands jobs.

The command used for copying is:

```
cp -Hpv ${CONTENTS} ${TMPDIR}
```

and if the copied content is larger than specified MB's, the job is killed with a message:

```
/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd/job24667725/slurm_script: line 78: 46020 Killed cp -Hpv ${CONTENTS} ${TMPDIR}
slurmstepd-e1370: error: Detected 1 oom-kill event(s) in StepId=(jobid).batch. Some of your processes may have been killed by the cgroup out-of-memory handler.
```

I've contacted cluster admins in that regard, and they just replied to reserve more RAM for the job. However, this results in an absurd amount of ram locked (basically wasted) for a week during the simulation, and used only for the moment when the results are copied back. Keeping in mind that I can (and often do) submit up to 5000 jobs at a time, I'm looking for some kind of hack to `cp` or `rsync` commands to force them not to cache to RAM or not to cache at all, while copying.

Will be glad for any comments.
Best regards.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "cached to RAM". Are you talking about the buffer sizes used by cp and/or rsync? It might help if you show us the actual copy command.

Comment: Sorry if I phrased the question wrong, it probably is the buffer size if it uses RAM. I based my question on the response I got from the system administrator, who wrote about cp using RAM as a cache. I've edited the post to include more details.